# ssjs not retrieving DE records

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I was able to retrieve the records from a DE in one of the SFMC account but is not working for other account.
Is there something else to be included in below ssjs code?

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.5");
try{

var myDE = DataExtension.Init("ENT.TSDelete");
var data = myDE.Rows.Retrieve();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var name = data[i].Name;
    var customerKey = data[i].CustomerKey;
    
    Write(name);
    Write(customerKey);
  }

 }
 catch (err) {
  Write("Error Message: " + Stringify(err.message) + Stringify(err.description));
 }
</script>
```

Comment: If on another account you were running this script on parent level, then you need to remote "ENT." prefix before Data Extension's name.

Comment: I am running this on child account. I used DE name as well as External Key but no data shows up

Comment: I was able to retrieve the data when the DE was present in local folder, but when using ENT. I cannot fetch the DE records for shared DE. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I do not believe the ENT. prefix works in the CORE library, same as it does not in WSProxy and SOAP (been a bit, so might be wrong...). I believe in order to access something in a shared folder you will need to utilize WSProxy and change the environment (ClientID) to the parent level when trying to retrieve or interact with anythign in Shared.

Answer (score 0):

I think this part needs to change:

```
myDE = DataExtension.Init("ENT.TSDelete");
```

The initiate DE function requires the DE's External Key. In sfmc DE External Keys can't have "." characters in them. Try your code with the DE's External Key.